# Updating a PHP variable through HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to be able to change the PHP variables `$dispname` and `$banstat` in the code below with a HTML form.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] == "login") {
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "foo";
$password = "bar";
$dbname = "wordpress";
$banstat = '1';
$dispname = "Brendan";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "UPDATE wp_oxygenpurchaseusers SET user_url=$banstat WHERE    display_name=$dispname";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
}
?>

</script>
<link href="http://jotform.us/static/formCss.css?3.3.8019" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://jotform.us/css/styles/nova.css?3.3.8019" />
<link type="text/css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" href="http://jotform.us/css/printForm.css?3.3.8019" />
<style type="text/css">
.form-label-left{
    width:150px !important;
}
.form-line{
    padding-top:12px;
    padding-bottom:12px;
}
.form-label-right{
    width:150px !important;
}
.form-all{
    width:650px;
    color:#555 !important;
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}
</style>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?p=login" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="formID" value="51970718174158" />
<div class="form-all">
<ul class="form-section page-section">
  <li id="cid_4" class="form-input-wide" data-type="control_head">
    <div class="form-header-group">
      <div class="header-text httal htvam">
        <h2 id="header_4" class="form-header">
          Ban Tool
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];  ?> method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="dispname"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="banstat"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
  <li style="display:none">
    Should be Empty:
    <input type="text" name="website" value="" />
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
<input type="hidden" id="simple_spc" name="simple_spc" value="51970718174158" />
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("si" + "mple" + "_spc").value = "51970718174158-51970718174158";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some multiple issues in your code.

Try

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] == "login")
{
    /* Database Connection Info */
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "foo";
    $password = "bar";
    $dbname = "wordpress";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error)
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    /* getting form values */
    $banstat = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['banstat']);//'1';
    $dispname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_GET['dispname']);

    $sql = "UPDATE wp_oxygenpurchaseusers SET user_url='$banstat' WHERE display_name='$dispname'";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)
    {
        echo "Record updated successfully";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
}
?>

</script>
<link href="http://jotform.us/static/formCss.css?3.3.8019" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://jotform.us/css/styles/nova.css?3.3.8019" />
<link type="text/css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" href="http://jotform.us/css/printForm.css?3.3.8019" />
<style type="text/css">
.form-label-left{
    width:150px !important;
}
.form-line{
    padding-top:12px;
    padding-bottom:12px;
}
.form-label-right{
    width:150px !important;
}
.form-all{
    width:650px;
    color:#555 !important;
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}
</style>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?p=login" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="formID" value="51970718174158" />
<div class="form-all">
<ul class="form-section page-section">
  <li id="cid_4" class="form-input-wide" data-type="control_head">
    <div class="form-header-group">
      <div class="header-text httal htvam">
        <h2 id="header_4" class="form-header">
          Ban Tool
        </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>

Name: <input type="text" name="dispname"><br>
E-mail: <input type="text" name="banstat"><br>

  <li style="display:none">
    Should be Empty:
    <input type="text" name="website" value="" />
  </li>

<input type="submit">
</form>
</ul>
</div>
```

**Errors in your code**

- You open two forms.
- You are using `post method` in form but using `get method` in php code.
- Your variables were not updating.

Comment: Hmm, It seems like it's working. It's submitting but it's not updating the value in the table or sending a error code. Thanks for the help again, I don't know what I'd do without everyone's help.

Comment: @BrendanOcheltree you mean "Record is not updated successfully"?

Comment: @BrendanOcheltree in that case you must `echo $sql;` before `if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)` and copy/paste the query in phpmyadmin to see your query is valid or not.

Comment: Yeah, it's still not echoing anything when I run it and put in data.

Comment: gimme the query you are getting after form submitting.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/wp-content/plugins/wuss_login/ban.php?formID=51970718174158&dispname=Brendan&banstat=1&website=

Comment: @BrendanOcheltree please fix the query by your self. I can't help you out till then you cannot tell me the correct issue in my answer. I can't access your local computer to see results.

Comment: i'll figure it out eventually, Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: @BrendanOcheltree Please accept my answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need get $_POST and set variable

```
$dispname = $_POST['name'];
```

***Errors in your code:***

You open two forms and just close one

If you want use post instead get check ***$_POST***

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] == "login") {
   if ($_POST) {
      //update variables and update bd
   }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I took both of the other answers provided from @javi and @Hassan and used them to re-write it, I took the majority of the code from Hassan's and then changed a few things using Javi's and put this together. I figured maybe someone else could use this. Thanks again guys.

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] == "login") {
if ($_POST) {
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "foo";
$password = "bar";
$dbname = "wordpress";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$banstat = $_POST['banstat'];
$dispname = $_POST['dispname'];
$sql = "UPDATE wp_oxygenpurchaseusers SET user_url=$banstat WHERE user_login='$dispname'";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
}
}
?>

</script>
<link href="http://jotform.us/static/formCss.css?3.3.8019" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://jotform.us/css/styles/nova.css?3.3.8019" />
<link type="text/css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" href="http://jotform.us/css/printForm.css?3.3.8019" />
<style type="text/css">
.form-label-left{
    width:150px !important;
}
.form-line{
    padding-top:12px;
    padding-bottom:12px;
}
.form-label-right{
    width:150px !important;
}
.form-all{
    width:650px;
    color:#555 !important;
    font-family:"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
  }
</style>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>?p=login" method="post">
Display Name: <input type="text" name="dispname"><br>
Ban Status: <input type="text" name="banstat"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
  <li style="display:none">
    Should be Empty:
    <input type="text" name="website" value="" />
  </li>
</ul>
```